# R: Currently unsupported data type when using period.apply

Tags: r, xts

First a reproducible example:

```
library(quantstrat)

getSymbols("AAPL")

Test<-period.apply(AAPL,endpoints(AAPL,on="weeks",k=10),ROC)
TestDF<-as.data.frame(Test)
```

I want to get the ROC for a certain stock or whatever for x weeks. Or in other words, I want to compare several stocks and rank them with their 10-week ROC, 20 week ROC etc.
Obviously the period apply works, however when I want to convert it to a data Frame and look at my data I always get this error:

```
Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`period.apply` requires a function that returns a single row. `ROC` does not return a single row. So define your own function to do that.

```
Test <- period.apply(AAPL, endpoints(AAPL,on="weeks",k=10),
  function(x) log(last(x)/coredata(first(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, almost what I'm looking for. I didn't state clearly what I need..basically I want to rank certain assets (I don't have HLOC data for them, only close data) according to their x-week ROC. But I want to rank them daily. So the function should actually return the same amount of rows as my original data, but the lookback period shifts of course every day..How would I achieve that in that apple example?

Comment: @MichiZH: then you're going about it backwards. 1) calculate a x-week ROC, then 2) call `apply.daily` on the x-week ROC with `function(x) rank(coredata(x))`.

Comment: ah ok getting closer thanks :-) My last problem is how to calculate an x-week ROC? I could use period n=50 for 10 week ROC but this isn't correct if there are Holidays in between or the very first data we have is only weekly anyway, there it's not correct either..

Comment: @MichiZH: You have to handle that manually. E.g. what's the x-week ROC on the day that's x-weeks after a holiday? It's undefined. You probably want to make your data regular by something like `merge(x, .xts(,seq(start(x),end(x),by="1 day")), fill=na.locf)`.

Comment: Thx alot, you're right..it's too undefined. Ok problem solved :-)